# pygtk vlc player does not play next track

Tags: pygtk, vlc, libvlc

I'm writing a small custom player based on libvlc. I've used much of the code from https://github.com/hartror/python-libvlc-bindings/blob/master/examples/gtkvlc.py that plays a single track just like I need.

Now I want to swtich to another track after previous has finished. To do that I catch callback "EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached" and in callback handler I write code:

```
<------>def endCallback(self,event):
<------><------>fname = vlc_controller.GetNextTrack()['url']
<------><------>self.w.set_title(fname)
<------><------>self.vlc.player.set_mrl(fname)
<------><------>self.w.set_title('after set_mrl')
<------><------>self.vlc.player.play()
<------><------>self.w.set_title('after play')
```

Now when this code gets executed it stucks on `self.vlc.player.set_mrl(fname)` and does not go any further and as a result I see NO NEXT TRACK.

I've tried different variations of this code using (`vlc.stop()`, `vlc.set_media` instead of `vlc.set_mrl`) but nothing works

Comment: So far I've ivestigated that set_media() causes a problem. It does not return

Comment: Found some workaround by using MediaListPlayer instead of MediaPlayer, but it also has some bugs. More details at http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=108750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally....
I think the best choise is to make multi threaded application on python
2 Threads:

1. Main thread - gtk.loop and displaying video an some other thinks
2. Additional thread that makes media switching.

For some time I was afraid of multithreading but now I know that this was the best way to do this task

Answer (score 0):

For those facing similar issue in C# (Xamarin), per VLC documentation, calling the VLC object from an event tied to the object may freeze the application. So they said to use the code below inside the trigger event.

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => PlayNext());
```

An example would be calling the code above inside the EndReach event.
Where PlayNext() is your own custom method to handle the next action you want to execute.
I struggled with this for about a day before seeing that portion of the documentation.

Comment: Can you please translate this code into python code?

Comment: i think it would be something like this  
threading.Thread(target=PlayNext()) 

PS: Just to add, i don't write python but this is what i could come up with by googling using the basic idea of the implementation.